# SharePoint 2010 Enterprise: Is FAST Search installed by default?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I thought I would play with FAST server this evening, and I think I might be going a bit crazy here.

I have an instance of SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise, and I can create FAST search sites.

In addition, my SQL Server instance has all the FAST_Query and FAST_Search databases set up.

Furthermore, the FAST search seems to be crawling correctly.

However when I try and search, I get an error from the search screen that says "The Search Request was unable to connect to the search service".

I have googled this hard, but all guidance on the internet seems to be around installing / configuring / trouble shooting the FAST Search Server for SharePoint. (Which is a separate install )

So my questions are:

A) Do I have a valid FAST Search Application already, or do I need to install FAST server separately?

B) If I do have a valid FAST Application, where can I find any documentation on the 'SharePoint enterprise" version?

Thanks in advance! Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAST is a separate product, and quite a heavyweight one too. It needs to be downloaded, installed and configured separately before you even think about the Sharepoint 2010 features - all you're enabling there is a service app and site collection that act as "place-holders", for want of a better word, inside sharepoint that FAST plugs into.

As for documentation, the stuff on technet is quite good:

[Microsoft install steps for FAST for SP2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381243.aspx)

[Microsoft's general guide to deploying FAST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee781286.aspx) (as you can see, quite a complex subject)